# Convert array into a hash

Tags: ruby

I try to learn map and group_by but it's difficult...

My array of arrays :

```
a = [ [1, 0, "a", "b"], [1, 1, "c", "d"], [2, 0, "e", "f"], [3, 1, "g", "h"] ]
```

Expected result :

```
b= {
     1=> {0=>["a", "b"], 1=>["c", "d"]} , 
     2=> {0=>["e", "f"]} , 
     3=> {1=>["g", "h"]}
   }
```

Group by the `first value`, the second value can just be `0` or `1`.

A starting :

```
a.group_by{ |e| e.shift}.map { |k, v| {k=>v.group_by{ |e| e.shift}} }

=> [{1=>{0=>[["a", "b"]], 1=>[["c", "d"]]}},
   {2=>{0=>[["e", "f"]]}}, {3=>{1=>[["g", "h"]]}}]
```

I want to get "a" and "b" with the 2 first values, it's the only solution that I've found... (using a hash of hash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a somewhat custom `group_by` I tend do just do it manually. `group_by` creates an Array of grouped values, so it creates `[["a", "b"]]` instead of `["a", "b"]`. In addition your code is destructive, i.e. it manipulates the value of `a`. That is only a bad thing if you plan on re using `a` later on in its original form, but important to note.

As I mentioned though, you might as well just loop through `a` once and build the desired structure instead of doing multiple `group_by`s.

```
b = {}
a.each do |aa|
 (b[aa[0]] ||= {})[aa[1]] = aa[2..3]
end
b # => {1=>{0=>["a", "b"], 1=>["c", "d"]}, 2=>{0=>["e", "f"]}, 3=>{1=>["g", "h"]}}
```

With `(b[aa[0]] ||= {})` we check for the existence of the key `aa[0]` in the Hash `b`. If it does not exist, we assign an empty Hash (`{}`) to that key. Following that, we insert the last two elements of `aa` (= `aa[2..3]`) into that Hash, with `aa[1]` as key.

Note that this does not account for duplicate primary + secondary keys. That is, if you have another entry `[1, 1, "x", "y"]` it will *overwrite* the entry of `[1, 1, "c", "d"]` because they both have keys `1` and `1`. You can fix that by storing the values in an Array, but then you might as well just do a double `group_by`. For example, with destructive behavior on `a`, handling "duplicates":

```
# Added [1, 1, "x", "y"], removed some others
a = [ [1, 0, "a", "b"], [1, 1, "c", "d"], [1, 1, "x", "y"] ]
b = Hash[a.group_by(&:shift).map { |k, v| [k, v.group_by(&:shift) ] }]
#=> {1=>{0=>[["a", "b"]], 1=>[["c", "d"], ["x", "y"]]}}
```

Comment: It become fast hard when we use complicated array/hash. I spent some hours to be looking for a solution. Thank you again for your explanation very useful ! Now, I can access to the data simply.

Comment: For your edit: Ok, there is never duplicate. (it's a result of a SQL group_by on first and second fields.) But it's interesting for later.

Comment: Daniël's point about your code being destructive is important! If you want to destroy an object you create in your method, [be my guest](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/be_my_guest), but I question whether it's ever a good idea to destroy an argument. Who knows what will become of your code in future, or who will have responsibility for it? When we pass an object to a method, we expect it to be treated with respect, so very bad things can happen if it's been abused. Intentionally modifying an argument (as desired by the calling method) is a different matter, of course.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if `group_by` is the simplest solution here:

```
a = [ [1, 0, "a", "b"], [1, 1, "c", "d"], [2, 0, "e", "f"], [3, 1, "g", "h"] ]

result = a.inject({}) do |acc,(a,b,c,d)|
  acc[a] ||= {}
  acc[a][b] = [c,d]
  acc
end

puts result.inspect
```

Will print:

```
{1=>{0=>["a", "b"], 1=>["c", "d"]}, 2=>{0=>["e", "f"]}, 3=>{1=>["g", "h"]}}
```

Also, avoid changing the items you're operating on directly (the `shift` calls), the collections you could be receiving in your code might not be yours to change.

Comment: Thank you too, I'll examine you code to know how it works but almost the same than Daniël Knippers' one.

Comment: @Alexis_user Yes, except it uses `.inject` instead of declaring the result above the loop like I do. The rest is exactly the same, except I squeezed more stuff on 1 line. Not sure why it received more upvotes ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
[[1, 0, "a", "b"], [1, 1, "c", "d"], [2, 0, "e", "f"], [3, 1, "g", "h"]].
    group_by{ |e| e.shift }.
    map{ |k, v| [k, v.inject({}) { |h, v| h[v.shift] = v; h }] }.
    to_h
#=> {1=>{0=>["a", "b"], 1=>["c", "d"]}, 2=>{0=>["e", "f"]}, 3=>{1=>["g", "h"]}}
```

Comment: Ahah thank you too ! Another way again but with `map` and `group_by`, good to learn ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do it (nondestructively) with two [Enumerable#group_by](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by)'s and an [Object#tap](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-tap). The elements of `a` (arrays) could could vary in size and the size of each could be two or greater.

**Code**

```
def convert(arr)
  h = arr.group_by(&:first)
  h.keys.each { |k| h[k] = h[k].group_by { |a| a[1] }
                               .tap { |g| g.keys.each { |j|
                                            g[j] = g[j].first[2..-1] } } }
  h
end
```

**Example**

```
a = [ [1, 0, "a", "b"], [1, 1, "c", "d"], [2, 0, "e", "f"], [3, 1, "g", "h"] ]
convert(a)
  #=> {1=>{0=>["a", "b"], 1=>["c", "d"]}, 2=>{0=>["e", "f"]}, 3=>{1=>["g", "h"]}}
```

**Explanation**

```
h = a.group_by(&:first)
  #=> {1=>[[1, 0, "a", "b"], [1, 1, "c", "d"]],
  #    2=>[[2, 0, "e", "f"]],
  #    3=>[[3, 1, "g", "h"]]}

keys = h.keys
  #=> [1, 2, 3]
```

The first value of keys passed into the block assigns the value `1` to the block variable `k`. We will set `h[1]` to a hash `f`, computed as follows.

```
f = h[k].group_by { |a| a[1] }
  #=> [[1, 0, "a", "b"], [1, 1, "c", "d"]].group_by { |a| a[1] }
  #=> {0=>[[1, 0, "a", "b"]], 1=>[[1, 1, "c", "d"]]}
```

We need to do further processing of this hash, so we capture it with `tap` and assign it to `tap`'s block variable `g` (i.e., `g` will initially equal `f` above). `g` will be returned by the block after modification.

We have

```
g.keys #=> [0, 1]
```

so `0` is the first value passed into `each`'s block and assigned to the block variable `j`. We then compute:

```
g[j] = g[j].first[2..-1]
  #=> g[0] = [[1, 0, "a", "b"]].first[2..-1]
  #=> ["a", "b"]
```

Similarly, when `g`'s second key (`1`) is passed into the block,

```
g[j] = g[j].first[2..-1]
  #=> g[1] = [[1, 1, "c", "d"]].first[2..-1]
  #=> ["c", "d"]
```

Ergo,

```
h[1] = g
  #=> {0=>["a", "b"], 1=>["c", "d"]}
```

`h[2]` and `h[3]` are computed similarly, giving us the desired result.

Comment: Wow, it's a real lesson ! Thank you ! I understand more ruby now ! It's with the type of this example that I learn more and more Ruby !